# Função Calculate no Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Uma coisa que não entendi na função `calculate` do Power BI é se os filtros que vc insere na função são acumulativos. Por exemplo, tenho a seguinte fórmula para calcular o *downside risk* de um determinado portfólio:

```
Downside Risk = calculate(STDEV.P(basesumarizada[Cota 1d]), basesumarizada[Data] >= DATE(MAX(Datas[Ano]),01,01), basesumarizada[Cota 1d] <= AVERAGE(basesumarizada[Cota 1d]))
```

E queria saber se o primeiro filtro `basesumarizada[Data] >= DATE(MAX(Datas[Ano]),01,01)` também é aplicado ao segundo filtro `basesumarizada[Cota 1d] <= AVERAGE(basesumarizada[Cota 1d])` e a função do segundo filtro `AVERAGE(basesumarizada[Cota 1d])`.

Comment: Sim são acumulativos: Medida = Calculate(Expressão, filtro1, filtro2, filtro3) ele vai aplicar os filtros na ordem em que são escritos, seguindo a lógica 1, 2, 3 e assim por diante. são acumulativos sim, você também pode utilizar dentro do CALCULATE o Filter(tabela, expressão), da na mesma.